# Modifying value of a key in object doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have one object say

```
requestObject: any = {
    "type": 'type1',
    "start": 0,
    "size": 10,
    "keywords": ['abcd','efgh'],
    filters: [],
  }
```

then I want to modify value for keyword so I did

```
 requestObject['keywords'] =  ['pqr']
```

but when I do console log for it.It shows same value.

```
"keywords": ['abcd','efgh'],
```

I tried delete key and then adding updated value with same key name but still the same.

```
delete requestObject.keywords
requestObject['keywords'] =  ['pqr'];
```

Detailed Description:

I have two sibling component lets say A and B(NgbModal). In component A I have requestobject. Now on click of a button in component A the component B(NgbModal) pops up where I can update value and hit submit. After submission I sent those values to Component A using event emitter and I capture it using

```
modalRef.componentInstance.filterApplied.subscribe((res: any) => {}
```

and I an trying to update my object in Component A. But it is not updating and giving same old values.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: probably a `this` issue. but we need to see more code.

Comment: is object frozen? does it allow mutation? context of "this"?

Comment: [It works](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYGwhgzhAEAiCmBbA9tA3gWAFDV9ATvAI4Cu8EALgPIBGAVvMBQFzRgB2AntALzrZ5B0AEQVOAB3jDWAcjGSAjDIA0AobmGUw+CtOgAGVTnUiIASwBeU1gsNr1wgNbxOAd2T4AJhD0BtGWA0wJ4q0DLwAGYA5gAWMgC6RibQEWYgFPD4EKy+ifbQAL75YOmZALLwABQAlKwAbshmnvzG6hQxZhAAdISk5NT0jBT+zm4e3gm80P7iRPgJANz5gsDI7BDIIPBdIMhRlQBSAMpUAHJdlPhm7FFmEZyV7Z3K0OwkICAvAEzV1UuthWwRSwdW00E8SFQfHY8FccEhNX+EJQXRKGXwFURQA) Please provide a [mre] where it does not work.

Comment: where did you put the  this.requestObject['keywords'] =  ['pqr'] ?   (it works for me https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4flixs)

Comment: I have modified code a bit. @ChrisRollins

Comment: I have tried following code to check if the object frozen 
console.log(Object.isFrozen(object1));
but it give false . so It is not frozen i guess

Comment: I added detail description. Please refer that as well

Comment: @Ennar.ch I checked link that you have shared. I know this is really straigh forward but for some reason its not working for me. Anyways I added more details in question if that helps you to understand problem in detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### You may be unintentionally bumping into "immutability".

I suspect your response object is coming back via [`HttpResponse`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpResponse), the body of which (according to the docs) is read-only.

Even if that's not the root cause here, [it's generally good practice to avoid directly modifying an object](https://wecodetheweb.com/2016/02/12/immutable-javascript-using-es6-and-beyond/#:~:text=First%20of%20all%2C%20why%20is,values%20cannot%20be%20mutated%20themselves.) such as a server response. The better approach is to create a new object and modify the new object.

Try one or both of these approaches:

```js
const requestObject: any = {
  "type": 'type1',
  "start": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "keywords": ['abcd','efgh'],
  filters: [],
}


// -----------
// solution 1:
// create a new object by spreading the old one and overwriting the 'keywords' item

const updatedRequest = {...requestObject, keywords: ['pqr'] }
console.log(updatedRequest)


// -----------
// solution 2:
// deep copy via JSON.stringify + JSON.parse

const clonedRequest = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(requestObject))
clonedRequest.keywords = ['pqr']
console.log(clonedRequest)
```

Answer (score 0):

When I tested the code in my console,

```
{
    "type": 'type1',
    "start": 0,
    "size": 10,
    "keywords": ['abcd','efgh'],
    filters: [],
}
```

was assigned to the variable `any`, not `requestObject`. That makes sense, as you are doing `any =`, which assigns everything after the = sign to `any` and does not return anything. Also, I don't think assigning using a colon works outside of object definitions. resultObject was undefined for me. You probably want to replace your assignment with

```
requestObject = {
    "type": 'type1',
    "start": 0,
    "size": 10,
    "keywords": ['abcd','efgh'],
    filters: [],
  }
```

Comment: The question is tagged as [tag:typescript] and `any` is a type definition.

Comment: anyways i tried this as well but didn't work. Its like object is not any changes to it. this is strange.